# how to make data.table omit extra col

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am trying to load a very large tab file by `data.table::fread`, my input data may have a extra tab before last col,like:

```
#The entire table is tab split, we just show finally tab as \t
col1    col2    col3\t # a tab here, I have many cols in fact (>3000)
1    2    9\t
1    3    3\t
3    9    6\t
```

I noted `fread` will infer colname if have extra col, but its not correctly

```
# fread infered as 
V1   col1    col2   col3
```

I dont want V1 exists in first

I have tried

1. shift and reset colname, it could worked, but now I plan to use select to select columns when I read the file, so I can't do that
2. use `data.table::fread(sep='\t', cmd=paste0('pigz -d -c ', input, ' | sed \'s/\t$//\''), select = select_col)`, Its worked, but seems very slower than process gz by `data.table::fread`

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the spaces between `col1`/`col2` (for all rows) is a single tab and not spaces? (The Stack interface doesn't make this easy or obvious, I'm inferring from the context of the question.)

Comment: I updated the post and now you can see that the entire table is TAB split, we just show finally tab as `\t` to illustrate the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with *this* result:

```r
fread("input.tab", sep="\t")
#     col1  col2  col3     V4
#    <int> <int> <int> <lgcl>
# 1:     1     2     9     NA
# 2:     1     3     3     NA
# 3:     3     9     6     NA
```

if you know how many columns exist ahead of time, then you can simply `select=` them:

```r
fread("input.tab", select=1:3)
#     col1  col2  col3
#    <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     2     9
# 2:     1     3     3
# 3:     3     9     6
```

Alternatively, if it's a large file and you want to be flexible, then you can do something like this:

```r
# read in just enough rows so that you are confident-enough 
# that the last column is all NA, a symptom of the trailing-tab
tmp <- fread("input.tab", sep="\t", nrows=10)
tmp
#     col1  col2  col3     V4
#    <int> <int> <int> <lgcl>
# 1:     1     2     9     NA
# 2:     1     3     3     NA
# 3:     3     9     6     NA
ncols <- ncol(tmp) - all(is.na(tmp[[ncol(tmp)]]))
ncols
# [1] 3
fread("input.tab", select=seq(ncols))
#     col1  col2  col3
#    <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     2     9
# 2:     1     3     3
# 3:     3     9     6
```

If you have predetermined column indices in `select_col`, then you can use

```r
fread(..., select = select_col[select_col < ncols])
```

This naive heuristic *can* be fooled if the tab-problem does not exist but the first `n` rows of the table are legitimately empty/null.

Answer (score 1):

Using `drop` from `fread`

Finding the desired number of columns through `system` with e.g. `awk`, assuming the unwanted column is the last one.

```
NUM = as.numeric(system('awk \'{print NF; exit}\' file', intern=T))
```

```
data.table::fread("file", header=T, drop=NUM + 1)
   col1 col2 col3
1:    1    2    9
2:    1    3    3
3:    3    9    6
```

Comment: In fact, the unwanted column is the last one， but some times fread will add a col with default colname V1 in first col, the drop params seems also work if I set it to last col, thank you